# SQLで、列Xの値がnのときの、列Yの値が最大の行を求めたい。

Tags: sql

```
select * from A where X=n and Y = ( select max(Y) from A where X=n);
```

でいいでしょうか？
これですと、`where X=n`が２か所にあり、もっと簡潔な、あるいは分かりやすい書き方はないでしょうか？

Comment: LEFT OUTER JOIN を使うのはどうでしょうか。`SELECT a.* FROM A a LEFT OUTER JOIN A b ON a.X = b.X AND a.Y < b.Y WHERE a.X = n AND b.X IS NULL;` 簡潔とは言い難いし、分かりやすくもありませんが。。。

Comment: 参考になりました。いろんな書き方がありますね。。。。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

「最大値」を「大きい順に並べた際の先頭の１つ」と考えるとシンプルに書けます。

```
SELECT TOP(1) *
FROM A
WHERE X=n
ORDER BY Y DESC
```

ただし該当行が複数存在する場合は正しい結果が得られません。

Comment: なるほど。たいへん勉強になりました。ありがとうございます

Answer (score 2):

@sayuri さんがおっしゃっているように、並べ替えて最初の行のみを取得する、が良さそうです。ただ、この「最初の行だけを取得する」は rdbms によって SQL の書き方が違います。

参考までに:

```
-- MS SQL Server, など
SELECT TOP(1) *
FROM A
WHERE X=n
ORDER BY Y DESC;

-- MySQL, PostgreSQL など
SELECT *
FROM A
WHERE X=n
ORDER BY Y DESC
LIMIT 1;

-- ANSI/ISO SQL:2008, DB2 など
SELECT *
FROM A
WHERE X=n
ORDER BY Y DESC
FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY;
```

Comment: DBごとに詳細にご解説いただきありがとうございました。

Comment: SQL Server 2012以降であれば３番目の[`FETCH`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2012/cc645577%28v%3dsql.110%29#%E3%82%A2%E3%83%89%E3%83%9B%E3%83%83%E3%82%AF-%E3%82%AF%E3%82%A8%E3%83%AA-%E3%83%9A%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B8%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B0%E3%81%AE%E5%AE%9F%E8%A3%85)も使えます。ただし[`OFFSET`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2012/ms188385(v%3dsql.110))の指定も必須なようです。